# Executing a function passed as an argument in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I'm trying to write a generic function that will block out the UI while an AJAX call is made.  What I'm trying to do is have a function A run any other function passed in as an argument.  This is what I've got so far:

```
function blockWhileLoading(fn, msg)
{
  if (msg == null)
  {
    msg = 'Please wait while the next page is loaded...';
  }

  $.blockUI(
  {
    message: '<h1>' + msg + '</h1>',
    css:
    { 
      border: 'none', 
      padding: '15px', 
      backgroundColor: '#E3D9BA', 
      '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
      '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
      color: '#4D2612'
    }
  }); 
  $('body').scrollLeft(0);

  setTimeout(function()
  {
    eval(fn);
    $.unblockUI();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Now when it comes time to eval the function, nothing seems to happen.  Is eval not the correct way to force a function to run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, eval is used to turn a chunk of "string" into JavaScript code at runtime.  Simply call `fn()`.  It's a function reference.

This is what eval does:

```
var myalert = "alert('test');";
eval(myalert);
```

Equivalent to:

```
eval("alert('test');");
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `fn();`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
fn();
```

Instead of `eval`.

Comment: Because I'm new to Javascript and don't know any better.  Hence the question.

Comment: @Sonny:  Sorry, the javascript looked a little advanced for someone new to javascript.

Comment: No worries... I'm actually inheriting a lot of this from someone else.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If `fn` is being passed as an object and not a string, calling `fn()` should work.